# error: ./dist/configure line 40:conf19087.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, berkeley-db

I get the error as above when trying to build Berkeley database version 4.5.20. I have unzipped the archive to /opt on UNIX. Please can anyone tell me what I need?

I do the following:

- Uncompress berkeley-db package in
  some directory. say in /opt
- cd to the build_unix directory
- ../dist/configure

When I run the last command it gives me the error as above. Does anyone know what I am missing here? Options? Another download?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have correct file permissions for the distribution folder. 
Try `chmod +w -R /opt/db-4.5.20`